# I want to validate drop down menu on value change not on submit button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have written this code for fetching data on submission of drop down menu, it is working on submit button click, but now I want this to work only on change of value in drop down menu, here is my working code.

```
<script language="javascript">
    function validFormDataCity() {
        if (document.getElementById("jobsbycitymenu").value == "Not Selected") {
            alert("Please select a City.");
            document.citysearch.jobsbycitymenu.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>   

<div id='jobsbycity'>
    <form id="citysearch" name="citysearch" method="POST" action="jobs-by-city-results">
        <p id='jobsbycitytitle'>Jobs by City</p>
        <select name="city" id='jobsbycitymenu'>
            <option value="Not Selected">---Select City---</option>
            <option value='Abbottabad'>Abbottabad</option>
            <option value='Arifwala'>Arifwala</option>
            <option value='Attock'>Attock</option>
            <option value='Badin'>Badin</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value=" Go " id='jobsbycitymenubtn' onclick="return validFormDataCity();"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

will be great thankful for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are tagging jQuery you could use:

```
$('#jobsbycitymenu').on('change', function(){
   $(this).closest('form').submit(); 
});
```

So your whole code (and please remove the inline script) would be:

```
$(function () {
    $('#jobsbycitymenu').on('change', function () {
        if (validFormDataCity()) $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });
    $('#citysearch').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault;
        return validFormDataCity();
    });

    function validFormDataCity() {
        if (document.getElementById("jobsbycitymenu").value == "Not Selected") {
            alert("Please select a City.");
            document.citysearch.jobsbycitymenu.focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true
    }
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vm4VB/)

For plain Javascript you can use [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5TSS/).

Comment: I have minimized the code now, can you modify this thing in my code. I will be thankful.

Comment: ...will update you soon, going away from system. thanks